# How to copy a div contenent to a txt file from a large html page

Tags: javascript, php, html

I need to copy the number of percent of the progress bar from this page to a txt file. (http://tienda.insidecraft.com/)

I have tried something like this:

```js
$(document).on("ready", function() {
    setInterval(querygoal, 5000);
  querygoal();
    $(".navbar-brand").tooltip({placement: "bottom", html: true});
  $("[data-toggle='tooltip']").tooltip();
});

  function querygoal() {
    $.ajax({
      url: "view-source:http://tienda.insidecraft.com/",
      method: "GET",
      success: function(res){
        if (res["status"]) {
          actualizarJugadores2(res["bar"]["style"]);
        }
      }
    });
  }

function actualizarJugadores2(num) {
  var digitos = ("" + num).split("");
  var elem = $(".goal").children("dd");
  elem.empty();
  for (index = 0; index < digitos.length; index++){
    elem.append("<span>" + digitos[index] + "</span>")
  }
  var color = "#F1A90F";

  if (num==0) {
    color = "#d9534f"
  }
  elem.children("span").css("background-color",color);
}
```

Anyone can help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No efforts shown; By the way- StackOverflow is not a code-writing service.

Comment: kindly also post suitable html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is tagged as PHP, so I guess that's an alternative? Simply parse the webpage with [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/index.htm). In the example beneath I use the style attribute to find the correct paragraph.

**Code:**

```
<?php
    include 'simple_html_dom.php';

    $html = file_get_html('http://tienda.insidecraft.com/');

    foreach($html->find('p[style="text-align:center; font-size:14px;"]') as $item) {
        $result = trim($item->plaintext);
    }

    $progress = explode( ' ', $result)[0];
    echo $progress;
?>
```

**Output:**

```
72%
```